# Where do these two equalities for the expectation value come from precisely? Doesn't $\Psi^* x \Psi = x |\Psi|^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Where do these two equalities for the expectation value come from precisely? :

$$\begin{align}
\langle x\rangle &= \int_{-\infty} ^\infty \Psi^* x \Psi\,\mathrm{d}x \\
\langle x^2\rangle &= \int_{-\infty} ^\infty x^2 |\Psi|^2\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}$$

Note: $\Psi$ is the wave function, and $\Psi^*$ is the complex conjugate of $\Psi$.

And are these two equalities also true? :

$$\begin{align}
\langle x\rangle &= \int_{-\infty} ^\infty x |\Psi|^2\,\mathrm{d}x \\
\langle x^2\rangle &= \int_{-\infty} ^\infty \Psi^* x^2 \Psi\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}$$

Don't we just have the equality $\Psi^* x \Psi = x |\Psi|^2$ ?

Comment: They come from the definition of the inner product on the $L^2$ space in the "position representation".

Comment: $\Psi=\Psi(x) \in \mathbb{C}$ so $\Psi^*(x)x\Psi(x)=x\Psi^*(x)\Psi(x)=x|\Psi(x)|^2$

Comment: Ya I have same problem dawgs

Answer (score 1):

Yes,both the set of equalities are true but only in the position representation where operator(x)=x.In the momentum representation,where operator(x) takes a different form they are not true

Comment: Could you develop the part where you say "In the momentum representation they are not true"? What are $<p>$ and $<p^2>$ equal to?